# How to get interpolated normal of triangle?

Tags: geometry, computer-vision

I have this 3D Triangle of which I want to get the interpolated normal of V3.

I know how to get the normal per triangle face, but I don't know how to get to interpolated normal.

[image: 3D Triangle]

I would calculate cross(v4-v1, v2-v1), but that would give me only the normal for the whole face.

Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are looking for the [vertex normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_normal). As stated in the link, it is the normalized average of the surface normals of the faces that contain that vertex.